# To select two columns from a table with individual order by?

Tags: plsql

My requirement is as below-

```
i/p
-------------------
col1   col2
1       d
3       b
2       e
5       a
4       c
```

And the expected output is -

```
O/p
-------------------
col1   col2
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
5       e
```

i.e. both the columns should be sorted in their own order.

Comment: Relational databases don't work this way.  We could give you a query which would generate this output, but what would the point be?

Comment: You're not changing the order here, you are actually changing data correspondence, which invalidates your end results

Comment: I do not want to keep the output data in any new table. This was an analytical question asked to me on an online forum. Though I was able to build the query to get the output, Wanted to know if there is any better method?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to write in Relational Databases. You should try to write a SELF JOIN query to make any type of relation both columns or the other way write a view inline of the second column.